# Is there a way to get/call the current working directory from inside a JSON?

Tags: json

I am not sure if I am asking this properly so I am going to try to elaborate.

If I were using a batch file, I could use the command

```
 echo %cd%
```

Which would tell me the current directory I am in. Even if the file is in *C:\Random\path*
If I opened the command prompt from the desktop and called *C:\Random\path\directory.cmd*

It would "echo" the *C:\Users\user\Desktop*

I want to do something similar with a JSON file.

I haven't tried much. I am new to JSON so this is an adventure.

Right now my JSON looks like:

```
 "search_paths": [{
     "recurse": false,
     "path": "C:\\Random\\path"
 }]
```

I want it to look something like:

```
 "search_paths": [{
     "recurse": false,
     "path": "%CD%"
 }]
```

Where **%CD%** is whatever JSON's equivalence is to it.

Thanks, and sorry if I'm not making as much sense as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It does not contain variables or placeholder, only data. There is no such thing as *"whatever JSON's equivalence is to it"*.

You can leave the path out of your JSON and modify the code that reads the JSON to add the current path into the `path` property.

Or you can use placeholders that have special meaning for the code that reads the JSON and write it to find such placeholders and replace them with values computed at runtime. F.e. `%CD%` could be such a placeholder and at runtime the code could replace it with the current directory.

The second approach is more flexible (and extendable). It allows you to have JSON that looks like this:

```
"search_paths": [
    {
        "recurse": false,
        "path": "%CD%"
    },
    {
        "recurse": true,
        "path": "C:\\Windows"
    },
]
```

Comment: JSON is data. You have to write some code to read and write it. And a Windows batch script is not the most appropriate tool to handle JSON.

Comment: It is actually a little more complicated than that. I am picking up work from someone who no longer works in my office.
There is an executable that is called within the batch scipt and even a few other json files that aren't directory-dependant

Comment: A very good tool to work with JSON files is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).